# how to access column values and do some calculation using python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, split, readline

Hii i have a text file that contain data like as below and saved in the name input.file

```
2.0_39_RAS.out  1.911157    1.5  80  0  10
2.8_29_BAS.out  2.224520    1.5  78  0  60
2.0_29_CGD.out  2.198376    1.5  85  0  28
2.0_28_MPK.out  1.945320    1.5  78  0  36
2.1_30_CLR.out  2.281479    1.5  78  0  16
```

I just want to do some calculations using column values and want to write its output in last column as follows:
for output: i need to multiply `4th` column with `6th` column value and want to divide it with second number(39,29,29,28,30) of .out string present in first column

```
                                                output
2.0_39_RAS.out  1.911157    1.5  80  0  10       (80*10)/39  
2.8_29_BAS.out  2.224520    1.5  78  0  60       (78*60)/29
2.0_29_CGD.out  2.198376    1.5  85  0  28       (85*28)/29
2.0_28_MPK.out  1.945320    1.5  78  0  36       (78*36)/28
2.1_30_CLR.out  2.281479    1.5  78  0  16       (78*16)/30
```

i tried to write a script for this

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

dir1 = glob.glob('/home/drem/data/input.file')

for files in dir1:
    x=files
    a = open(x,'r')
    b = a.readlines()
    a.close()
    for line in b:
        columns=line.split()
        print(columns)
        col4=columns[3]
        print(col4)
```

However, it doesn't access the column values and doesn't do the calculations ...i hope some expert will help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend using `pandas` for this kind of tabular data.

Comment: can you please help on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas for such table/column-based calculations, but you should read the docs and do some tutorials so that you understand each line:

The basic idea is to load the dataset using the CSV parser and turn it into a `pandas.DataFrame` where you can manipulate the data column-wise.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(
    "input.file",
    delim_whitespace=True,
    names=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    index_col=False)

df["result"] = df["D"] * df["F"] / df["A"].apply(lambda x: int(x.split("_")[1]))
print(df)
```

Gives you:

```
                A         B    C   D  E   F      result
0  2.0_39_RAS.out  1.911157  1.5  80  0  10   20.512821
1  2.8_29_BAS.out  2.224520  1.5  78  0  60  161.379310
2  2.0_29_CGD.out  2.198376  1.5  85  0  28   82.068966
3  2.0_28_MPK.out  1.945320  1.5  78  0  36  100.285714
4  2.1_30_CLR.out  2.281479  1.5  78  0  16   41.600000
```

More info is available here: https://pandas.pydata.org

Comment: however i donot in dexes like  A B C D E F  as well as 0 1 2 3 4

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The example does exactly what you asked for. You can name the columns whatever you like.

Comment: index headers i need to remove

Comment: Then remove them.

Comment: how can u please suggest

Comment: I showed you how it works and pointed you to the documentation. Now it's your turn to do the work and figure out yourself how to adapt it to your specific problem. We are certainly not here to do the work for you.

Comment: please sir ...suggest some solutions

Comment: panda is difficult for me to under stand i need simple python solutions

Comment: The solution is above, all other details you can figure out by learning how to program in Python and how to use Pandas. StackOverflow is not here to teach you how to program. Please work yourself through the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html